# Ошибка asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

Tags: python, бот, asyncio

недавно начал изучать асинхронную библиотеку aiovk для написания бота и сразу же столкнулся со странной ошибкой. Прочитав [документацию aiovk](https://github.com/Fahreeve/aiovk) написал небольшой код, который исправно работает до определённого момента, а именно до 2 ночи, почему-то именно в это время(проверял несколько дней) программа вылетает с ошибкой.
Сам Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/OTHERS/bot/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\bin\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/OTHERS/bot/test.py", line 15, in main
    data = await longpoll.wait()
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiovk\longpoll.py", line 62, in wait
    code, response = await self.api._session.driver.get_text(
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiovk\drivers.py", line 61, in get_text
    async with self.session.get(url, params=params, timeout=timeout or self.timeout) as response:
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 504, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 860, in start
    self._continue = None
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 596, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Если кто-то сможет помочь мне разобраться в чём проблема, то буду крайне признателен.
Код:

```
async def main():
    async with aiovk.TokenSession(access_token=TOKEN()) as session:
        api = API(session)
        longpoll = BotsLongPoll(session, mode=8, group_id=VK_GROUP_ID())

        while True:
            data = await longpoll.wait()
            updates = data['updates']
            for event in updates:
                if event['type'] == 'message_new':
                    if event['object']['message']['text'].lower() == 'qqq':
                        await api("messages.send",
                                  peer_id=event['object']['message']['peer_id'],
                                  random_id=0,
                                  message="q")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо увидеть всю трассировку ошибки

Comment: wait наверное рвется, зверни его в try

Comment: @AlexeyLeshchenko добавил трассировку

Comment: @eri  в каком смысле рвётся? Прерывается соединение, в результате чего вылетает ошибка? Просто я пробовал конструкцию try except, но ошибка всё равно оставалась, единственная мысль которая приходила в голову ```except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError as TE: pass```, но я пока ещё не реализовывал её. Это конечно может сработать, но я не знаю насколько это важная ошибка и каковы причины возникновения и можно ли её просто игнорировать

Answer (score 1):

Из трассировки видно, что там есть строка:

```
File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiovk\drivers.py", line 61, in get_text
async with self.session.get(url, params=params, timeout=timeout or self.timeout) as response:
```

То есть, параметр `timeout` в`BotsLongPoll` и управляет временем таймаута. Его можно установить при инициализации объекта:

```
longpoll = BotsLongPoll(session, mode=8,
    group_id=VK_GROUP_ID(), timeout=10000000)
```

Comment: А для чего выставляется такой большой таймаут? Или это просто как пример?

Comment: Конечно, пример. Вы уже сможете под свои нужды подставить нужное число

Comment: Попробовал добавить timeout и всё равно не помогло, выбивает эту же ошибку

Comment: Пригляделся и увидел   `File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 504, in _request     await resp.start(conn)`. То есть, проблема с установлением соединения с сервером, попытка которой отваливается по таймауту. Может, на сервере что-то происходит в 2 часа ночи? Не пробовали переждать 10 мин и снова восстановить цикл?

Comment: > Может, на сервере что-то происходит в 2 часа ночи?
Возможно это какое-то запланированное действие, вроде перезагрузки сервера, хотя программа крашится в интервале 1-25 минут после 02:00. 
>Не пробовали переждать 10 мин и снова восстановить цикл? 
Пробовал сразу перезапускать программу и всё нормально работало, но опять же, до 2 ночи следующего дня. А если Вы имеете в виду восстановление цикла без прерывания самой программы, то я это делать пока не умею, кроме как отловить ошибку с помощью `except` и закинуть туда `pass`

Comment: Да, только time.sleep вместо pass :)

Comment: Да, пробовал, ничего не вышло, но задержку ставил вроде 1 секунды, сейчас уже начинаю думать, что мало и стоит попробовать поставить больше.

Comment: После отлова ошибки попробовал time.sleep(60) и вроде как после всё работает без проблем, но пока с выводами спешить не буду, мало ли что-то пойдёт не так

Comment: @MESQ Поскольку там бесконечный цикл, то в какой-то момент соединение все же должно наладиться :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py
```

исправьте таймаут и будет вам Щастье

```
async def start_polling(self,
                        timeout=200,
                        relax=0.1,
                        limit=None,
                        reset_webhook=None,
                        fast: bool = True,
                        error_sleep: int = 5,
                        allowed_updates: typing.Optional[typing.List[str]] = None):
```